# Which format/tool to store 'basic' informations?

Tags: disassembly, tools, debuggers

It's really a productivity bottleneck when various analysis tools can't share information.

What's an efficient way to store symbols+comments+structures, so that they can be easily imported into other reversing tools?

---

I used to rely on SoftIce's IceDump extension to load/save IDA symbols, or load exported MAP symbols from IDA into OllyDbg via gofather+'s GoDup, but nothing recent nor portable.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is not really clear.

Comment: I rewrote it, with a real question this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential tool would be QuarkLabs' [qb-sync](http://www.quarkslab.com/fr-blog+list+1024), which advertises:

- Synchronization between IDA and WinDbg, OllyDbg2, GDB
- Source code available (GNU GPL 3)

Comment: Link only answers are not considered answers. You should add a short description. http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64/should-questions-contain-quotes-if-they-refer-to-external-sources

Comment: ok, I added a short description based on their doc.

Comment: Would it be possible to expand this a little bit more? I've made some edits, you should be able to see where you can add other potentially good features.